# How to read just first 5 folders inside a directory : Spark

Tags: json, scala, file, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list of folders under a directory (for eg: 2016/06/03/00/File.json.gz")). Currently I am reading all the files with :

```
val df = sqlContext.jsonFile("s3://testData/2016/06/*/*/*") 
df.show()
```

But I want to read just first 5 folders inside 06 (all the folders are like 01...30 - days and each have hour folders -00..23 which has the josnfiles)

Can I do something like :

```
val df = sqlContext.jsonFile("s3://testData/2016/06/0*/*/*")
```

I want to read just 01, 02, 03, 04 ,05 folders (5 days) and leave the rest

Is there any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
val df = sqlContext.jsonFile("s3://testData/2016/06/0[1-5]/*/*")
```